# ConfigMgr WebService API Calls

Tags: windows, curl, soap, sccm

at the moment I try to connect my application via api with the [ConfigMgr Webservice](https://github.com/NickolajA/ConfigMgrWebService), but send my SOAP API request via `curl` I always get a 400 error.

We are writting our own application to "talk" with the SCCM and because we cannot use PowerShell (cause of company restrictions) we are trying to use the [ConfigMgr Webservice](https://github.com/NickolajA/ConfigMgrWebService). Is anyone here, that have some experience with this little API and can point me in the right direction for speaking with it?

At the moment I try to get this endpoint `GetCWVersion`.

If you need further infos, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using python instead of testing around in `curl`.
With the `requests` library it is quite simple.

```
"""Just an example for a soap request"""
import requests

host = "host"
secret = "secret"
filter = "filter"

url = "https://" + host + "/ConfigMgrWebService/ConfigMgr.asmx"
payload ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <soap12:Body>
                    <GetCMDeviceCollections xmlns="http://www.scconfigmgr.com">
                    <secret>{secret}</secret>
                    <filter>{filter}</filter>
                    </GetCMDeviceCollections>
                </soap12:Body>
            </soap12:Envelope>""".format(secret=secret, filter=filter)
headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
}
    
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify = False)
print(response.text)
```